# How to preload a viewcontroller in UIPageViewController? Swipe delay

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have 3 views in my pageviewcontroller, all of them load tableviews. When I swipe from the first view to the left or right there is a small delay. After the initial swipe the delay goes away.

I have figured out that it is because the xml parsing/Json parsing slows down the viewdidload of both viewcontrollers.

How could I preload the viewcontrollers so that I get a smooth swipe with no delay in the pageviewcontroller?

Comment: The lengthy parsing of your JSON files isn't going away. You **should** perform that operation on a background (read: non-UI) queue, but at some point of your navigation flow the user will always be potentially delayed by the yet-not-loaded data. Do the usual thing and use progress indicators, etc.

Answer (score 2):

What I did for this problem was making an instance for each `viewController` and call `controller.view.layoutSubViews()` before putting them into the array of `UIPageViewController`. Furthermore, if your are using `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`, you need to call `reloadData()` when you get data from server.